# I need help developing a google script to generate a product list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very green at google script but I am trying to build a project that will:

1. take 2 inputs (a name and item #) on a list on sheet A (pink cells in image) and copy/paste them to specific 2 cell range (green cells in image) at the top of the sheet. These values generate an output on the first 4 rows of the sheet (blue cells) that is a template for my products. I did creat named ranges for those cells. I think...
   Image ->[Picture of My "SheetA"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Cvg.png)
2. Insert 4 rows on the top of sheet B. *This is an image of [Sheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBxzv.png)
3. Copy these new values from the first 4 rows on sheet A and paste them into the newly inserted rows on sheet B.
4. Repeat

I have been trying to build the function myself, but I am very inexperienced. I really do just want to learn though, so if you can help me understand anything that gets me closer to making this work, I would really appreciate it!

Here is my code so far:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Prepare sheet...', functionName: 'prepareSheet_'},
    {name: 'Generate products...', functionName: 'generateProduct_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Directions', menuItems);
}

function generateProduct_() {
    var i = 0
    var generatorCells = nameCell + ":" + numberCell;
    var nameCell = new String("A"+i);
    var numberCell = new String("B"+i);
    var generatorCells = nameCell + ":" + numberCell;
    var nameCellResults = new String("A"+(i*5));
    var numberCellResults = new String("B"+(i*5));
    for (var i=11;CELL_EMPTY = false; i++) {
  spreadsheet.getRange(generatorCells).copyTo(getRange(productGenCells)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false;
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:5').copyTo(sheet.getRange(genResults),{contentsOnly:true}, spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Results'), true);
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 4);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('productGen!2:5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('productGen'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  }
};
```

Comment: what is the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code through https://jshint.com/ (or similar) it will pick up numerous issues. Some corrected code below. But the most glaring issue is the conditional test in the for loop.

1) Firstly a single = (assignment) operator is used instead of a double == (test)
2) The value that is supposedly tested for CELL_EMPTY is not set in the loop.
3) this should probably be a while loop anyway.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Prepare sheet...', functionName: 'prepareSheet_'},
    {name: 'Generate products...', functionName: 'generateProduct_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Directions', menuItems);
}

function generateProduct() {
    var i = 0;
    var nameCell = "A"+i;
    var numberCell = "B"+i;
    var generatorCells = nameCell + ":" + numberCell;
    var nameCellResults = "A"+(i*5);
    var numberCellResults = "B"+(i*5);
    for (i=11;CELL_EMPTY == false; i++) {
        spreadsheet.getRange(generatorCells.copyTo(getRange(productGenCells)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
          spreadsheet.getRange('2:5').copyTo(sheet.getRange(genResults),{contentsOnly:true}, spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, true);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Results'), true);
          spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 4);
          spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
          spreadsheet.getRange('productGen!2:5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('productGen'), true);
          spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
        }
}
```